# Understanding a map in "Algebraic Group Schemes in characteristic 0 are reduced"

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, schemes, algebraic-groups, group-schemes

Let $G$ be a group scheme of finite type over a field $k$.
In his paper [Algebraic Group Schemes in characteristic 0 are reduced](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01403391), Oort says that since $G$ is not affine a homomorphism $\mathscr{O}_{G}\to \mathscr{O}_G\otimes \mathscr{O}_G$ does not exist in general. But for $e\in G$, the identity element of $G$ and $\mathfrak{m}\subseteq \mathscr{O}_{G,e}$ the maximal ideal, the multpilication map $G\times G\to G$, induces a ring homomorphism
$\mathscr{O}_{G,e}\to \mathscr{O}_{G,e}/\mathfrak{m}^q\otimes \mathscr{O}_{G,e}/\mathfrak{m}^q$ (for any integer $q$).

My question: How is this map defined?

Comment: note that the tensor product of two local rings is not a local ring: $k[x]/(x^2)\otimes_k k[x]/(x^2)$ is not a local ring.

Comment: There is for any group scheme $G$ an isomorphism of tangent space $T_{(e,e)}(G\times G) \cong T_e(G)\oplus T_e(G)$. There is a similar isomorphism for cotangent-spaces:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3541848/tangent-space-of-a-product-of-algebraic-group/3987723#3987723

Comment: @hm2020 - can you elaborate on the connection to the question?

Comment: for any ideal $I\subseteq A$ where $A$ is a commutative $k$-algebra, there are several maps $A \rightarrow A/I\otimes_k A/I$: $p(a):=a\otimes 1, q(a):=1\otimes a$. You should explain the construction in Oorts paper - how does Oort arrive at the specified map?

Comment: He says that this map is induced by the multiplication map $G\times G\to G$.

Comment: If you assume that $e$ is a $k$-rational point it follows $\mathcal{P}^l_{G/k}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{G,e}} \kappa(e) \cong \mathcal{O}_{G,e}/\mathfrak{m}_e^{l+1}$, where $\mathcal{P}^l_{G/k}$is the l'th jet bundle of $G$ (= a higher order module of Kahler differentials) - maybe this can be used.

Comment: For the module of Kahler differentials there is always an map induced by the multiplication: $m^*\Omega^1_{G/k} \rightarrow \Omega^1_{G\times G/k}$. There are similar maps for higher order jet bundles.

Comment: A problem is that the cotangent space is "additive" in the following sense: There is an isomorphism $\Omega^1_{G\times G/k}\otimes \kappa(e,e) \cong \Omega^1_{G/k}\otimes \kappa(e) \oplus \Omega^1_{G/k}\otimes \kappa(e)$ (see the above post).

Comment: The cotangent space of the product is the direct sum of the cotangent space of the factors. There is an isomorphism of $\kappa(e)$-vector spaces $\Omega^1_{G/k}\otimes \kappa(e) \cong \mathfrak{m}_e/\mathfrak{m}_e^2$.

Comment: If $e\in U:=Spec(A)\subseteq G$ is open affine, let $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq A\otimes_k A$ be the maximal ideal of $(e,e)$ and let $\mathfrak{q} \subseteq A$ be the ideal of $e$. There is a canonical map $A_{\mathfrak{q}} \rightarrow (A\otimes_k A)_{\mathfrak{p}}$. But there appears to be no natural map $(A\otimes_k A)_{\mathfrak{p}} \rightarrow A_{\mathfrak{q}}\otimes_k A_{\mathfrak{q}}$. If there was such a map you could compose with the map

Comment: $A_{\mathfrak{q}}\otimes_k A_{\mathfrak{q}} \rightarrow A_{\mathfrak{q}}/ \mathfrak{q}^lA_{\mathfrak{q}}   \otimes_k A_{\mathfrak{q}}/\mathfrak{q}^lA_{\mathfrak{q}} $ and arrive at a definition of your map. There is a map in the other direction $A_{\mathfrak{q}}\otimes_k A_{\mathfrak{q}} \rightarrow (A\otimes_k A)_{\mathfrak{p}}$.

Comment: I totally agree, this is the reason for my question. In general $(A\times_k A)_{\mathfrak{p}}$  is a localization of $A_q\otimes A_q$.
So what is the reason for this? A somewhat similar argument appears in Mumford's "Lectures on Curves on an Algebraic Surface" Lecture 25.

Comment: Look for an example where the map $(A\otimes_k A)_{\mathfrak{p}} \rightarrow A_{\mathfrak{q}}\otimes_k A_{\mathfrak{q}}$ does not exist. If you find an example, you have a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

**Comment:** If $e∈U:=Spec(A)⊆G$ is open affine, let $p⊆A⊗_k A$ be the maximal ideal of $(e,e)$ and let $q⊆A$ be the ideal of $e$. There is a canonical map $A_q→(A⊗_k A)_p$. But there appears to be no natural map $(A⊗_k A)_p→A_q⊗_k A_q$. If there was such a map you could compose with the map

$$A_q⊗_k A_q→A_q/q^lA_q⊗_k A_q/q^lA_q$$

and arrive at a definition of your map. There is a map in the other direction

$$A_q⊗_k A_q→(A⊗_k A)_p.$$

**Your comment:** I totally agree, this is the reason for my question. In general $(A\otimes_k A)_p$ is a localization of $A_q⊗_k A_q$. So what is the reason for this? A somewhat similar argument appears in Mumford's "Lectures on Curves on an Algebraic Surface" Lecture 25.

**Comment:** Look for an example where the map $(A⊗_k A)_p→A_q⊗_k A_q$ does not exist. If you find an example, you have a counterexample.

There is a canonical map

$$\phi:A\otimes_k A \rightarrow A_q \otimes_k A_q$$

and if $S:=A\otimes_k A-p$ has the property that $\phi(S)$ consists of units, there is an induced map $(A\otimes_k A)_p \rightarrow A_q \otimes_k A_q$.